# import maven archetypes from GitHub

Tags: maven, github, intellij-idea, maven-archetype, dropwizard

I want to start a new Drop-Wizard project. There is a maven archetype specified in the DW github ([here](https://github.com/nicktelford/dropwizard/tree/feature/maven-archetypes/dropwizard-archetypes)) . But i don't know how to import it into my Intellij Idea's **add Archtype** option. Being specific, which link i have to provide in the **Repository** field. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the dropwizard archetypes are not available in maven central repository you have to:

- **Clone the [dropwizard github forked project by niktelford](https://github.com/nicktelford/dropwizard/tree/feature/maven-archetypes/dropwizard-archetypes)**:
   `$ git clone git@github.com:nicktelford/dropwizard.git`
- **Checkout the feature branch**:
   `$ git checkout feature/maven-archetypes`
- **Move to dropwizard-archetypes module folder:**
   `$ cd dropwizard/dropwizard-archetypes`
- **Install the dropwizard archetypes to your local repository:**
  `$ mvn install` (The archetype samples are then added to local repository under $LOCAL_REPO/io/dropwizard/archetypes/)
- **Make the dropwizard-create script executable:**
   `$ cd target/classes`
   `$ chmod +x dropwizard-create`
- **Create your project sample:**
   `$ ./dropwizard-create com.sample sample`

Here you have your project generated then you can import it into Intellij IDEA as a maven project.

Comment: Figured it on my own. Anyway thanks for replying. Is there any way to add the compiled jar file to my local maven archetype repository for future use?

Comment: Once installed the archetypes are availble under the described path and you can use them whenever you want but actually I can't find a way t import them into intellij archetypes without specifying the repo url, sorry

Answer (score 3):

Currently, to create a Dropwizard project from Maven archetype using IntelliJ IDEA one should select File>New>Project from menu. Then, in the dialog it is necessary to select **Maven** on the left-hand side, check **Create from archetype** at the top and press the **Add Archetype** button.

[image: New project IDEA]

After that in a dialog that appears

[image: Dropwizard Archetype]

one should enter:

- GroupId:io.dropwizard.archetypes
- ArtifactId:java-simple
- Version:0.8.2

The information about the latest Dropwizard version can be obtained [here](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/getting-started.html).

After the aforementioned actions are completed, the desired archetype appears in the list.
[image: IDEA archetype list]

Then one should press **Next** an fill the project's artifact and group ids and press **Next**. For this particular archetype it is necessary that a property called **name** should be added which is later used to produce names of application and configuration classes.

[image: Add name property]

After pressing **Next** and **Finish**, one can see a newly created project.

[image: Dropwizard project]

Alternatively, one could create a project using a Command Line Interface as described [here](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.com/2015/01/getting-started-with-dropwizard-first.html), and then [import the project into IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/importing-project-from-maven-model.html).

**Update:** Added a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/doz1HzxLUkU).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the dropwizard-archetypes are only available in the feature branch feature/maven-archetypes, so you have to substitute the following for steps 2-3 above:

```
$ cd dropwizard
$ mvn checkout feature/dropwizard-archetypes
$ mvn -Dfindbugs.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true install
```

(findbugs and javadoc tend to run into trouble of various kinds on some modules).

Then of course step 4 becomes

```
$ cd dropwizard-archetypes/target/classes
$ chmod +x dropwizard-create
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to get the resulting executable to run under 64-bit Windows 7.